# Visual Studio 2017: Add reference assemblies not matching .Net Framework target

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly, visual-studio-2017

I am facing a strange behavior with Visual Studio 2017 when adding a reference to a C#.Net project. The project itself targets .Net Framework 4.5.2, however when adding System assemblies (System.Data in my case), the .Net 4.0 dll gets added instead.

From reading other posts, I understand that what is displayed in the UI can be deceiving and that while the Add Reference screen shows the list of all assemblies with a “4.0.0.0” version, the version that will end up in the references will be the one matching the project’s target framework.

However, when looking into the details of the assembly, I can definitely observe that the wrong dll is used as it does not include the method that I need, and Visual Studio won’t compile.

[Added assembly shows the right path in the properties, but wrong content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHSGw.png)

When using Visual studio 2015 though, switching the target framework of the project does change the referenced dll.

Has anyone observed this behavior with Visual Studio 2017? If yes, is there a new option / parameter I am missing somewhere?

Comment: The framework version number does not have anything to do with the [AssemblyVersion] number in the DLLs.  The framework number gets increased when more assemblies get added or there is a significant set of bug fixes or behavior changes.  The core assemblies, like System.Data, still have the 4.0.0.0 version number they had in .NET 4.0 and behave the same.  The CLR is likewise v4.0.30319 for all 4.x framework versions.